# How can I add (not replace!) a default route upon OpenVPN connection?

Tags: openvpn, gateway, route, iproute2

When I run `sudo openvpn foo.conf` I do not yet have a default gateway defined.

Once the connection is established, I run `sudo ip route add default via X.X.X.X`, where X.X.X.X is the **local** IP of the newly created **tun** interface.

That works perfectly fine.

Avoiding the manual step, I would like OpenVPN do this for me. So I add `route default` to the configuration.

This fails with: **NOTE: unable to redirect default gateway -- Cannot read current default gateway from system**

Why does it want a current default gateway when I would replace it anyway? How can I have OpenVPN add the default gateway correctly (without using external scripts)?

Comment: This `;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"` is in my config file. I believe it's one of the default, but commented options. You may be able to add `push "route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0"` to define a default route.

Comment: You can't `redirect-gateway` when you don't actually have one to redirect!

Comment: @user38537 I have no control over the other side. Anyway, 0.0.0.0 is not the same as "default". Tried that already with `route 0.0.0.0..`. @Michael: Not using said option;

Answer (score 0):

The best practice of the openvpn is adding the two routes (`0.0.0.0/1` and `128.0.0.0/1`) to avoid replace the original default route. For this you can use the route options in the open vpn client configuration file:

```
route 0.0.0.0 128.0.0.0
route 128.0.0.0 128.0.0.0
```